# how to wrap long words and keep normal words non-wraped

Tags: html, css

in the example below I need to wrap the long word so that `story` keeps original `padding` and `width`
`word-break: break-all` - works fine but unwanted result is - the rest of the text is wrapped inproperly
for example lorem is wraped on `l`-`orem` or `lore`-`m`

How to wrap long words and keep normal words non-wraped?

```css
.grid{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
}
.grida{
background:orange;
}
.story{
    padding:25px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
<div class='grida'></div>
<div class='gridb'>
<div class='story'>
<a href = "https://loremipsum.com">loremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsum</a>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `word-break` to `break-word`:

```css
.grid{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
}
.grida{
background:orange;
}
.story{
    padding:25px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
<div class='grida'></div>
<div class='gridb'>
<div class='story'>
<a href = "https://loremipsum.com">loremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsumloremipsum</a>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
</div>
</div>
</div>
```